# Is there a spell or potion that allows you to rest immediately?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, potions, rests

Is there a spell or potion in Pathfinder which allows characters to rest immediately, i.e., have their daily spells and abilities which were used up available again?

My googling hasn't found anything, so I might have to homebrew it otherwise for my one-time plot need.

Comment: Reminder: comments are for clarifying content, not posting small or incomplete answers. Please use answer posts to submit answers instead. Prior comments containing answers have been removed.

Comment: Note that many divine casters don't need rest at all, instead preparing spells at the beginning of the day or at a particular time. It might be useful if you specified the class that needed this effect to occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're a mythic character, then [Recuperation](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-heroes#TOC-Recuperation-Ex-) gives you a full night's rest in 1 hour, including refreshing daily abilities such as spells. You can do this multiple times per day, limited only by your mythic power points. The item [Cornucopia of Plenty](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-magic-items/other-magic-items#TOC-Cornucopia-of-Plenty) makes this more power-efficient, but still requires a mythic character.

Answer (score 5):

**Wish**

Wish is the only spell that even has a possibility of this sort of thing happening. From the rulebook:

> You may try to use wish to produce greater effects than these, but doing so is dangerous. (The wish may pervert your intent into a literal but undesirable fulfillment or only a partial fulfillment, at the GM's discretion.

Keep in mind that wish has a material component cost of a 25,000 GP diamond. If one of my players used his wish to ask for a rest and reset of all his spells, I would either curse them to sleep until the next morning, or simply transport them through time to the next morning fully rested. (Depending on how vindictive I was feeling at the moment.)

*This sort of power you are talking about is insanely powerful*, and **I would strongly advise against homebrewing anything to do it**. If you do, the cost needs to be absurd to the point where it's like a one-shot per campaign.

If it *is* for a one-shot plot purpose, or you don't have any casters who can cast wish, you could always have some sort of artifact that loses its power after a single use (Ring of Ultimate Wish, anyone?), or a potion that has an ingredient that is extremely rare, such that the party could never find all the parts to make it again.

Comment: I was more thinking of doing it as a one time thing for very plot driven reason. So it won't be something that will happen constantly

Comment: @jonatzin If that's the case, I would totally use the wish spell. Alternatively, if it's for a plot purpose, or you don't have any casters who can cast wish, you could always have some sort of artifact that loses its power after a single use (ring of ultimate wish anyone?), or a potion that has an ingredient that is extremely rare, such that the party could never find all the parts to make it again.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that the potion is *insanely* powerful. The DMG gives some latitude for deciding how many combat encounters per in-game day and it provides recommended amounts of XP per day. For example it says you can do 6-8 "normal"-difficulty encounters, but I prefer to do fewer harder ones. If the DM leans towards multiple encounters rated "hard" or "deadly", then giving 25% of the party back some spells no longer seems like that big of a deal.

Comment: @acbabis It really depends on the level of the party. At later levels, caster characters are (generally) already vastly more powerful than their martial counterparts. The semblance of inter-class balance comes from the limit of spells per day. If you remove that restriction, caster classes all of a sudden become even more attractive than martial classes. That said, multiple encounters per day just means you need to be smarter about spell selection and usage. It also means wands, staves, etc etc.

Answer (score 4):

The traditional approach is to go to a plane with very fast [flowing time](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/environment/the-planes#TOC-Flowing-Time), such as whatever plane is described in the explanation:

> One may travel to another plane, spend a year there, and then return to the Material Plane to find that only 6 seconds have elapsed.

That’s even faster than you need: you just need 8 or 9 hours (depending on the nature of your spellcasting, i.e. whether you need an extra hour to prepare spells) to elapse in a round.

Finding such a plane, much less finding a safe place in such a plane in which to sleep for 8 hours, is quite a task, but if you manage to do it, you can go there, rest, and come back to wherever you were, with all your spells (barring whichever you use to return) available.

This sort of thing is very, very high-end optimization, and frowned on at the overwhelming majority of tables. Your GM most likely will not allow it, and most likely shouldn’t.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, I'm the GM and it's something I want to happen once and it's very plot driven. I was just wondering if there was something that provided this capability

Comment: @jonatzin Something like that should just be done by GM fiat; call it an artifact, divine intervention, or whatever you like. They wouldn’t publish something like that explicitly because it is such a powerful effect.